# .NET Cyrstal Reports: Separar información

Tags: vb.net, .net, crystal-reports

me encuentro con un problema que me está costando un poco resolver:
Tengo que mostrar un reporte sobre un DataTable que tengo cargado con datos (Nombre, Documento, Sexo, Edad, Año) y debo mostrarlo separado por "Años". No hay problema para agrupar ya que la información la ordeno por año y ya está, la cuestión es que quiero mostrar en el Reporte una diferencia entre cada "masa" de datos separado por años.

Estuve leyendo mucho sobre Sub-Reportes pero lo he intentado y no queda como quiero.

Dejo un ejemplo del tipo de reporte al que estoy apuntando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ya me he respondido Jacguate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución.
Lo que quería era que mi información estuviera agrupada por el campo "Año" entonces encontré que Crystal permite **Agrupar**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]